# iterating through childs of div with class insides :nth-child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to iterate through the children of the div with class insides.
so far it has been a failure.
here is the html:

```
<div class="insides">
    <div class="pen" style="background-image:url('images/video.png');background-size:cover">
       <div class="cover"></div>
       <div class="items">
           <div class="title">
           fullscreen-centered-blurred-video-background
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            Quick video covers fullscreen with blur effect and grayscale (looping) with working input fields
        </div>
        <a class="button button-secondary button-small" href="http://codepen.io/peterbs/pen/QpyrMb">
            View On CodePen
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pen" style="background-image:url('images/form.png');background-size:cover">
       <div class="cover"></div>
       <div class="items">
            <div class="title">
            Loading-form
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            Simple and fast loading form that is displayed after loading is finished
        </div>
        <a class="button button-secondary button-small" href="http://codepen.io/peterbs/pen/PpZExY">
            View On CodePen
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pen" style="background-image:url('images/horizontal.png');background-size:cover">
       <div class="cover"></div>
       <div class="items">
           <div class="title">
            align-vertically
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            Very easy javascript that aligns children vertically within its parents because css had weak support.
        </div>
        <a class="button button-secondary button-small" href="http://codepen.io/peterbs/pen/aJNEvB">
            View On CodePen
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pen" style="background-image:url('images/navbar.png');background-size:cover">
       <div class="cover"></div>
       <div class="items">
           <div class="title">
            navbar-animations
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            navigation bar with 3 different animations. One more will be coming soon.
        </div>
        <a class="button button-secondary button-small" href="http://codepen.io/peterbs/pen/dvMpyV">
            View On CodePen
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.pen has opacity: 0
and when the user scrolls down a little bit i want them to show 1 by 1. 
here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('.content').css('transform', 'translateY( '+ scroll / 2 +'px )' );

       if(scroll > 120){
             for(x = 0; x <= 4 ; x++){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.insides:nth-child('+ x +')').css('opacity','1');
                }, 700*x);
            }
        }else{
             for(x = 0; x <= 4 ; x++){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.insides:nth-child('+ x +')').css('opacity','0');
                }, 700*x);
            }
        }

    });

    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

         if(scroll > 120){
             for(x = 0; x <= 4 ; x++){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.insides:nth-child('+ x +')').css('opacity','1');
                }, 700*x);
            }
        }else{
             for(x = 0; x <= 4 ; x++){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.insides:nth-child('+ x +')').css('opacity','0');
                }, 700*x);
            }
        }

});
```

i honestly have no idea why it is not working. it just doesn't show
here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f176ch6r/ 
it doesn't look perfect in the fiddle but it does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

- the nth-child selector must be applied on your .pen elements
- because of the setTimeout all your $('.insides:nth-child('+ x +')') selectors will have the same x

here is what I would write:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _onScroll);
_onScroll();

function _onScroll(){
    var x,
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
        show = scroll > 120;

    $('.content').css('transform', 'translateY( '+ scroll / 2 +'px )' );
    for(x = 0; x <= 4 ; x++){
        _toggle(x, show);
    }
}

function _toggle(index, bShow){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.insides .pen:nth-child('+ (index + 1) +')').css('opacity', bShow ? 1 : 0);
    }, 700*index);
}
```

I also updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f176ch6r/3/)